# Name of files is not changed when python script is run

Tags: python, loops, file, directory

I was creating a simple python script that iterates through files in a directory and changes the names of the files based on a `num` variable that increases by one after each iteration.
Here is the code used, with the directory and files involved.

```
import os

directory = 'JAN'
num = 1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    new_f = f'JAN-{num}.txt'.format(num=num)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        os.rename(filename, new_f)
    num += 1
    print(new_f)
```

```
Current Files

├── _JAN
│   ├── first.txt
│   ├── second.txt
│   ├── third.txt
│   └── fourth.txt

Desired Changes to Files

├── _JAN
│   ├── JAN-1.txt
│   ├── JAN-2.txt
│   ├── JAN-3.txt
│   └── JAN-4.txt
```

I have tried a few iterations and the only output received is each new file name printed to the console with no changes to the file names within the `JAN` directory.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `new_f = os.path.join(directory, f'JAN-{num}.txt'.format(num=num))` ?

Comment: `os.listdir(directory)` returns filenames, not full path's. So same here: `if os.path.isfile(f): ...`

Comment: `os.path.isfile(filename)` will always be `False` unless `directory` is `.`. See comment above for how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments say, you need to check for f not filename and you also need to save it to the dir:

```
import os
directory = 'JAN'
num = 1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    new_f = os.path.join(directory, f'JAN-{num}.txt'.format(num=num))
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        os.rename(f, new_f)
    num += 1
    print(new_f)
```

You can also use enumerate instead of num:

```
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(directory), 1):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    new_f = os.path.join(directory, f'JAN-{i}.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        os.rename(f, new_f)
    print(new_f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'll have to check out enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

additional note: there is no need to use `.format` when you use `f''` already.

```
import os

directory = 'JAN'
num = 1
os.chdir(directory)  # Changes current working directory to "JAN"

for filename in os.listdir(): # equals to: for filename in current directory.
    new_f = f'{directory}-{num}.txt'
    if os.path.isfile(filename):  # now it can detect filename since we've changed the current working directory.
        os.rename(filename, new_f)
        num += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll remember for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir). It's an iterator whose object are `os.DirEntry` instances which make them easy to work with (have attributes such as `name`, `path`, `is_file`, ...), in particular you can bypass the side-effect of `listdir` that returns basenames and not paths.

Here assumed that the files are already in the right order in the directory.

```
import os

directory = 'JAN'

new_f_template = os.path.join(directory, 'JAN-{}.txt')
with os.scandir(directory) as files:
    for i, f in enumerate(files, 1):
        if f.is_file():
            new_f = new_f_template.format(i)

            os.rename(f.path, new_f)
            print(f"{f.name} -> {new_f}")
```